# AngularJS - own filter

Tags: angularjs, filter, module, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to make my own filter due to some tutorials in AngularJS.

My code looks like this

```
angular.module('fooAppFilters', []).filter('scenarioDate', function() {
  return function(input) {
    // do some changes on input
    return input;
  };
});

angular.module('fooApp', ['fooAppFilters']);

function FooCtrl($scope, $http, $ogrAppFilters) {
  // ...
}
```

Anyway, I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Unknown provider: $fooAppFiltersProvider <- $fooAppFilters
```

Can you give me a hint please? I am stuck here for a longer time.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only inject service into controller, not module.

To create filters, registering filters with module, then use ng-app="fooApp" in HTML to bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you! I am very new to angular, this helped me.